# Extra hole in a waterhead

Tags: wiring, conduit, fiber-optic

I have this outside conduit for my internet copper cable and internet fiber. And I guess one of the wires is electrical power? It is mounted on my outside wall, high-up and hard to reach by ladder, even.

The conduit has this waterhead mounted on to it, that feeds the cables.

I need it to accommodate one more cable.

Can I punch out one more circular tab? They seem very sturdy? Do they need drilling? or punching from the back?

How do I remove the whole plastic sub-assembly from the metal spout?

[image: spout]

### UPDATE

The other side of the conduit looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That device is called a "weatherhead".  Can you verify that that's low voltage cable running in there, not electrical power?

Comment: Where does the other end of that pipe go?

Comment: Have grouding wire, didn't even bother to connect it to the grounding block, and didn't connect the CATV cable ground to the grounding block. Not an impressive job, Cable Guys.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Should I connect the green wire to the metal clamp?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of differnece with nothing else connecting, but yes, that would be the correct configuration for those. The clamp does not seem to have as many connection points (for additional grounds) as is typical for these things, but it clearly is supposed to be a grounding point for the communications cables.

Answer (score 2):

That's a weatherhead (as already mentioned in a comment) and you don't generally "remove the whole thing" (it should be glued on) you remove the top of it - in your case, apparently by removing the two screws at the sides, then lifting it off (mine snap off and on, to the best of my recall.)

If it has your "internet copper" in it, there should be no line voltage power in it, so verifying what the third cable actually is, is going to be required, and correcting it *(removing it from this conduit)* if it is line voltage power would be required before doing anything else with it.

The knockouts are there to run cables or wires through, so you can open one up to add a cable, once you've eliminated the possibility that there is line voltage on one of the cables. That might involve a hammer, a hammer and a punch, a utility knife, or a drill. If cutting or drilling, make sure you don't damage cables already in place.

If it's hard to reach even from a ladder, you need a bigger ladder, or you should rent a manlift, or staging, or some other means to safely access it. *Emergency room visits and funerals are both expensive.*